# Can I use multiple H1 tags in bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, dom, html-heading

I am not able to decide how to structure my HTML document and how to place heading tags

Following is my page structure

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            //Logo and navigation using bootstrap code - site wide
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div>
        //bootstrap carouse
        <div>
            .....
            .....
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active" style="background-image: url('assets/ssp365.jpg')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading for slide 1</h1>
                        <span>Brief description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url('assets/ssp365.jpg')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading for slide 2</h1>
                        <span>Brief description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url('assets/ssp365.jpg')">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Heading for slide 3</h1>
                        <span>Brief description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ......
            ......

            //rest of the content
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        //page footer - site wide
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know if I can use H1's the way I have used within the bootstrap carousel caption.

I always find it difficult to decide where to place H1 tag when there is a carousel used at the top of the **home pag**e and there is no real heading to describe the page. Also, normally a home page tries to cover a lot of content about the entire website so it becomes difficult to structure the page.

Please help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use css styling with font-size. Give page header a bigger size than the carousel hearders.

```
.page-header{
    font-size : 50px;
}

.carousel-header{
    font-size : 35px;
}
```

Try these.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple `H1` tags in a page or document. The purpose of an H1 is to be the main header of a part of the page that is (thematically/semantically) independent from other similar parts/sections of the page.